# Working with bootstrap

Tags: twitter-bootstrap, c#-4.0

I'm working with bootstrap and I'm trying to place a easy thing like two textboxes with their labels and a checkbox button in a row and in another row two textboxes and a button and when I preview them I see the checkbox and the button always in different row, why?.

This is my code:

```
 <div class="row">

    <div class="col-md-4">
         <asp:Label ID="lblTitulo" runat="server" AssociatedControlID="txtTitulo" Text="Título"></asp:Label><asp:TextBox ID="txtTitulo" CssClass="form-control" runat="server"></asp:TextBox>
    </div>

    <div class="col-md-3"> 
        <asp:Label ID="lblOrden" AssociatedControlID="txtOrden" runat="server" Text="Orden"></asp:Label><asp:TextBox ID="txtOrden" CssClass="form-control" runat="server"></asp:TextBox>
    </div>
    <div class="col-md-4">   
        <asp:Button ID="btnAnadirDimension" CssClass="btn btn-danger" runat="server" Text="Añadir Dimensión" OnClick="btnAnadirDimension_Click" />
    </div>

</div>


<div class="row">
    <div class="col-md-3">
          <asp:Label ID="lblNombre" runat="server" AssociatedControlID="txtNombre" Text="Nombre"/><asp:TextBox ID="txtNombre" CssClass="form-control" runat="server"/>
    </div>
    <div class="col-md-3">
        <asp:Label ID="lblFecha" AssociatedControlID="txtFecha" runat="server" Text="Fecha"/><asp:TextBox ID="txtFecha" CssClass="form-control" runat="server"/>
    </div>
     <div class="col-md-2">
        <div class="checkbox">
              <asp:Label ID="lblDiponible" AssociatedControlID="chkDisponible" runat="server" Text=""/> <asp:CheckBox ID="chkDisponible" runat="server" Text="Disponible" />
        </div>
     </div>
    <div class="col-md-4"></div>
  </div>
```

So, why happen this?. How can I fix it?. Thanks so much

Answer (score 1):

Try modifying your code as below:

```
<div class="row">
 <div class="col-md-12">
   <div class="col-md-4">
     <asp:Label ID="lblTitulo" runat="server" AssociatedControlID="txtTitulo" Text="Título"></asp:Label><asp:TextBox ID="txtTitulo" CssClass="form-control" runat="server">
     </asp:TextBox>
   </div>   
   <div class="col-md-4"> 
     <asp:Label ID="lblOrden" AssociatedControlID="txtOrden" runat="server" Text="Orden"></asp:Label><asp:TextBox ID="txtOrden" CssClass="form-control" runat="server">
     </asp:TextBox>
   </div>
   <div class="col-md-4"> 
     <asp:Button ID="btnAnadirDimension" CssClass="btn btn-danger" runat="server" Text="Añadir Dimensión" OnClick="btnAnadirDimension_Click" />
   </div>
  </div>
</div>
<div class="row">
 <div class="col-md-12">
   <div class="col-md-4">
    <asp:Label ID="lblNombre" runat="server" AssociatedControlID="txtNombre" Text="Nombre"/><asp:TextBox ID="txtNombre" CssClass="form-control" runat="server"/>
</div>
<div class="col-md-4">
    <asp:Label ID="lblFecha" AssociatedControlID="txtFecha" runat="server" Text="Fecha"/><asp:TextBox ID="txtFecha" CssClass="form-control" runat="server"/>
</div>
 <div class="col-md-4">
    <div class="checkbox">
          <asp:Label ID="lblDiponible" AssociatedControlID="chkDisponible" runat="server" Text=""/> <asp:CheckBox ID="chkDisponible" runat="server" Text="Disponible" />
    </div>
 </div>  
 </div>
</div>
```